# How do I graph simple X-Y data in Teechart?

Tags: delphi, teechart, fastreport

I'm using Delphi and Fast reports, specifically the TeeChart object inside Fast Reports.
I'm trying to plot a scatter graph (preferably with a line between the points)
Four points of typical X,Y data might look like this

- X=10, Y=35
- X=15, Y=40
- X=23, Y=44
- X=27, Y=8

I've set the X axis automatic to false and set a min of 0 and a max of 30.

However, when Teechart plots the points it plots the Y values at the correct height but puts them in X positions 0, 1, 2, 3 instead of 10, 15, 23, 27

This even happens when I hard code the data by setting 'Data Source' to 'Fixed Data' and putting 35;40;44;8 in the Y values box and 10;15;23;27 in the X values box.

How do I set up Teechart to plot the points at the correct X-Y coordinates?

Comment: How do you provide data for line series? AddXY?

Comment: Within Fast Reports its done by pointing the X and Y of the chart to the relevant fields in the dataset containing the data you want to plot. However you can also 'hard code' it as I mentioned above by typing the data values directly into the X and Y edit boxes of the chart object at design time. That's what I did to test it to make sure it wasn't anything in the dataset causing the issue. But with the values above they are still plotted in X positions 0, 1, 2 and 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use AddXY method, for example:

```
  Series1.AddXY(10, 35);
  Series1.AddXY(15, 40);
  Series1.AddXY(23, 44);
  Series1.AddXY(27, 8);
```

You should also be able to modify values like this:

```
  Chart1[0].XValues[0]:=10;
  Chart1[0].XValues[1]:=15;
  Chart1[0].XValues[2]:=23;
  Chart1[0].XValues[3]:=27;
  Chart1[0].XValues[0]:=35;
  Chart1[0].XValues[1]:=40;
  Chart1[0].XValues[2]:=44;
  Chart1[0].XValues[3]:=8;
```

That's how it should be done in TeeChart outside of FastReports. If none of those solutions works you might need to contact FastReports technical support.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure doing that way is possible though as the data comes from a database. This won't just be one graph. Each graph will have up to 30 points on it but I won't know which points exist until run time so for example if I only have 20 points of data, I won't have a value to give to Chart1[0].Xvalues[21] (There will also be around 12 graphs per record in another table and there are around 1200 records in that table. I will investigate if its feasible to extract the data from the tab

Comment: the table before the report displays the graph and programatically enter the values as you suggest by using AddXY inside a loop running up to the number of points I have. Answer accepted as it is obviously correct, even though it may take some fiddling to apply the principle to the object in Fast Reports.

Comment: didn't you mean for the last four XValues to by YValues?